recharts responsive pie chart with legend
I have a problem when showing the Pie and the legend. Apparently, if the legend is to wide, it tends to remove space from the pie chart. Shouldn't the responsive container calculate the values to set an appropriate overall width??
  <div
    className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center
  h-full w-full"
  >
    <ResponsiveContainer
    >
      <PieChart>
        <Pie
          data={questionnaire?.chartData}
          paddingAngle={5}
          label
          nameKey={"name"}
          dataKey={"value"}
          innerRadius={60}
          outerRadius={80}
        >
          {questionnaire?.chartData.map(
            (x, index) => (
              <Cell
                stroke="0"
                key={`cell-${index}`}
                fill={`${COLORS[index]}`}
              />
            )
          )}
        </Pie>
        <Legend
          layout="vertical"
          align="right"
          verticalAlign="middle"
        />
        <Tooltip />
      </PieChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  </div>



Linking the answer from GH https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/4487
